# How to pick part of a string in a column with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .tsv Dataframe with a specific column with more than one value separated by commas. It looks like this:

```
     Col1         Col2         Col3

1    star1  HIP1, KOI1, Gaia1  3.4
2    star2  HIP2, KOI2, Gaia2  4.3
3    star3  HIP3, KOI3, Gaia3  7.2
```

My objective is to take only part of the string value from column 2, so that I only have one of the options separated by commas. In this case, it would be the KOIs. It'd look like this:

```
     Col1   Col2  Col3

1    star1  KOI1  3.4
2    star2  KOI2  4.3
3    star3  KOI3  7.2
```

Is there a way to do it, considering the numbers right after KOI(x) do not follow an ordinal order (as in the example)?
I've tried using the `str.lsplit()` and split function, but the code returns the message: `'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'lsplit'`. This is what I tried:

```
for i in df['Col2']:
    df['Col2'][i] = df['Col2'].str.lsptrip(', K').str[0]
```

I would then try adding the missing 'K' letter to the string, when I had it isolated, but never got to that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pd.Series.str.extract` too:

```
df['Col2']=df['Col2'].str.extract('.*, (K.*), .*')
```

---

Same as this, with `pd.Series.str.split`:

```
df['Col2']=df['Col2'].str.split(', ').str[1]
```

---

Output:

```
df
    Col1  Col2  Col3
1  star1  KOI1   3.4
2  star2  KOI2   4.3
3  star3  KOI3   7.2
```

Comment: Thank you, the extract function worked well. For some reason some values after the KOI were still shown in a few rows, but I aplied the split function to remove everything after the first comma and all was left were the KOI values I wanted. ;)